# How to use composite types as parameters with Npgsql and Telerik OpenAccess

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, stored-procedures, telerik, npgsql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 stored procedure:

```
FUNCTION g_savedx(_cpatient text, o view_dx, n view_dx) RETURNS void
```

where view_dx is a table. If I understand the PostgreSQL manual correctly, when used as a parameter to a stored procedure, only the TYPE is used. Hence, the table will be seen here as if I used CREATE TYPE.

Now Telerik EntityFramework compiles the following definition in the Domain Model:

```
        public int SaveDx(string cpatient, Object o, Object n)
    {
        OAParameter parameterCpatient = new OAParameter();
        parameterCpatient.ParameterName = "_cpatient";
        parameterCpatient.Size = -1;
        if(cpatient != null)
        {
            parameterCpatient.Value = cpatient;
        }   
        else
        {
            parameterCpatient.DbType = DbType.String;
            parameterCpatient.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        OAParameter parameterO = new OAParameter();
        parameterO.ParameterName = "o";
        parameterO.Value = o;

        OAParameter parameterN = new OAParameter();
        parameterN.ParameterName = "n";
        parameterN.Value = n;

        int queryResult = this.ExecuteNonQuery("SELECT * FROM \"public\".\"g_savedx\"(_cpatient, o, n)", CommandType.Text, parameterCpatient, parameterO, parameterN);

        return queryResult;
    }
```

Upon compiling, Telerik complains with:

> The specified clr type 'Object' is not valid for the parameter n of the procedure 'g_savedx'.

Attempts at "Fixing" the error by telling Telerik to use CLR Type System.Object consistently fail.

This ultimately is leading me to suspect that Telerik is using Npgsql as the interface to the PostgreSQL database and that Telerik is looking for a DBType of View_dx as reported by the PostgreSQL database. This type, ofcourse, does not exist in either the NpgsqlDbType enumerations nor System.Data DbType enumeration.

Somebody please tell me I'm wrong! Or, how to fix this, as I'd really like to use the PostgreSQL stored procedure with a composite type as a parameter.

Any help is most appreciated.